# shell script “${array[@]}” expansion: first and last entry have extra characters

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting

I have a shell script that uses an array. The script cycle through the entries of the array but for some reason the first and last entry has a problem.

The array:

```
Queue_Names=( CLQueue DLQ ExpiryQueue )
```

The for Loop:

```
for i in “${Queue_Names[@]}”
do
     #do stuff
done
```

I can see in the console and shows that for the first entry it shows: �CLQueue.
The last entry shows: ExpiryQueue�

I'm guessing these are markers to know the start and end of the array. Unfortunately it is interfering with the functionality of the script. I use these Queue names to search for something and it fails to find it because of the added character. How do I get rid of them or is there a code change I do to avoid the problem?

Comment: The guess is wrong: These are not markers built into bash. Bash has no such thing; its arrays are just collections of NUL-terminated strings.

Comment: Thus, you'll need to provide a reproducer. If I copy and paste `Queue_Names=( CLQueue DLQ ExpiryQueue )`, and `printf '%s\n' "${Queue_Names[@]}"`, I get the exact names, no extra characters.

Comment: Try to use some plain text editor... :)

Comment: Oh! The problem is the quotes!

Comment: Your script has "smart quotes" around the array reference instead of ordinary ASCII quotes, exactly as you present it here.  The funny characters are a representation of them in a different encoding or font.  This probably arises from editing the script in a word processor instead of a text editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`“${Queue_Names[@]}”` is not `"${Queue_Names[@]}"`, because `“”` is not `""`.

"Smart quotes" aren't recognized as quotes at all in bash; thus, the effect is the same as if the expansion had been unquoted -- string-splitting and glob-expansion on array contents -- with the literal "quotes" grafted around the start and end characters.

You need to use real quotes -- `""` -- not opening/closing "smart quotes" created by some word processing software or corporate email tools.

Comment: I copied it from a website and I didn't realize the quotes weren't the regular quotes. I probably would never have figure that out. THANKS!!! And it works now