# Using bash variables as paths to executable and file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a simple bash script using variables so that we can easily replace the file locations in the future. But I must be missing something here. I have this bash command here:

```
/Applications/Wakanda\ 1.1.4\ Enterprise/wakanda-enterprise-server.app/Contents/MacOS/wakanda-enterprise-server /Users/steveduisterhof/Desktop/GwS_Jeannie1.1.3/Jeannie\ Solution/Jeannie.waSolution
```

And that works, but when I try to do this bash script:

```
WAKSERV=/Applications/Wakanda\ 1.1.4\ Enterprise/wakanda-enterprise-server.app/Contents/MacOS/wakanda-enterprise-server

JEANNIESOL=/Users/steveduisterhof/Desktop/GwS_Jeannie1.1.3/Jeannie\ Solution/Jeannie.waSolution

“$WAKSERV” “$JEANNIESOL”
```

It gives the error

```
Mac-Pro:~ steveduisterhof$
/Users/steveduisterhof/Desktop/startJeannie ; exit;
/Users/steveduisterhof/Desktop/startJeannie: line 8: “??: command not found
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I'm rather new to this, so it might be something obvious, but I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: `“` is not `"`. Only ASCII quotes are syntactic to the shell.

Comment: You are using the wrong type of quotes. They need to be plain ASCII quotes (`"`), not Unicode U+201C (`“`) and U+201D (`”`).

Comment: If we were going to close this as duplicate rather than typo, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702745/bash-export-java-home-library-java-javavirtualmachines-jdk1-8-0-144-jdk-co is a candidate. Likewise, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548455/shell-script-array-expansion-first-and-last-entry-have-extra-characters (both having different descriptions, but the same underlying cause and the same fix).

Comment: Always turn off "smart quotes" when you're editing programs. AFAIK, there are no programming languages that use curly quotes, they all use `'` and/or `"`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just using textedit on mac for making my script. Havent really had this problem elsewhere, maybe I should just use another program to edit the script.

Comment: Yeah, just replacing the quotes in another text program places the right ones.

Comment: when using textedit on mac for creating or editing a script, first do format -> make plain text before starting.